# Make GCC look for headers in <dir> before ./

Tags: c, gcc, include-path

### Background:

I am putting together a test environment for an embedded project. Since it's an embedded project it tries to access hardware registers e.g. ADC results, timer settings, interrupt flags...

These registers are implemented automatically by Halcogen (it's a TI processor), as defines pointing to specific addresses.

```
    #pragma system_include

    #ifndef __REG_FLASH_H__
    #define __REG_FLASH_H__

    /* USER CODE BEGIN (0) */
    /* USER CODE END */

    #include "sys_common.h"

    typedef volatile struct flashWBase
    {
        uint32 FRDCNTL;       /* 0x0000 */
        uint32   rsvd1;       /* 0x0004 */
        .
        .
        .
        uint32 EESTATUS;      /* 0x031C */
        uint32 EEUNCERRADD;   /* 0x0320 */
    } flashWBASE_t;

    #define flashWREG ((flashWBASE_t *)(0xFFF87000U)) //<--- This one

    #endif
```

### My attempted solution:

In order to compile and run this code on a MinGW Win7 machine these specific addresses need to be re-defined to be pointing to observable and mutable variables. I have a Python script that analyzes the source code; creating a new header file using the same name in a common directory containing:

```
    #ifndef _COMMON_INCLUDES_REG_FLASH_H_
    #define _COMMON_INCLUDES_REG_FLASH_H_

    #include "..\..\W2_Library\Halcogen\Include\reg_flash.h" //<--- original Halcogen header

    #undef flashWREG
    flashWBASE_t _flashWREG;
    #define flashWREG (&_flashWREG)

    #endif
```

I have made many attempts using `-I-`, `-I<dir>` and `-iquote` to redirect inclusion of the headers getting farthest using the deprecated `-I-` to make GCC ignore the `.` directory. I would however rather have my `Common` folder precede the `.` than ignoring all together. Adding a `-I.` does not seem to be the same thing, I get the feeling it expands to the directory of the source code and doesn't stay "relative" as GCC delves deeper into the inclusion tree like the original `.` do.

Letting my Python script clone the entire header, replacing only the HW address with a variable, could be a solution. Just redefining the register defines in a separate header does however feel less prone to break.

### Question:

Is there any other ways to alter the search order?
I have read several questions about `-I-` but none has really had any answers as to how you get around the behaviour. [This question](/q/3162510) is pretty close but unlike that user, I am not using precompiled headers.

There are a few assumptions above and please correct me if they are wrong!

Comment: A quick search turned up [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html#Search-Path), the -nostdinc in addition to using -I might be of help here. I am posting this as a comment rather than answer because I don't know if it really answers your question and I don't have a linux box handy to try this out at the moment.

Comment: If you add a path to be searched using the `-I` option, then you can use the `<>` syntax to include files in that directory, and the preprocessor will then look in the added search paths for the file.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want.  I'd suggest that you compile with gcc --verbose and give us the search path it output for both version of include, as well as the command line argument you gave and the search path you'd have liked.  BTW `-I.` looks in the directory where gcc has been invoked, while -I- remove the possibility to look in the directory of the file containing the include directive, so they are indeed different.

Comment: @JamesH Thanks for the find but using the `-nostdinc` will remove all standard include paths except the `.` reference leaving it to still be the first one to be searched.

Comment: @Joachim The directories added with `-I<dir>`will be searched after the default `.`reference.

Comment: @Enok82 I just tested with GCC version 4.7, using two header files, `./foo.h` and `./t/foo.h`. If I used `#include <foo.h>` without any special option then `./foo.h` was included. If I added `-It` to add the `t` directory to the search path then `./t/foo.h` was included. So no, `.` is not searched first. If I use `#include "foo.h"` *then* the local `.` directory is searched first. So add the directory with `-I` and then use `#include <your_file.h>` (with the angle-brackets), and it should work.

Comment: @Joachim Sorry missed that the angle brackets were key for this to work. My problem then is that this is a test environment for an embedded project which code base is not really mine to alter as i wish. Having the code base owners changing `" "` to `< >` is however an alternative if nothing else works and it won't cause any problems. Tack så mycket!

Comment: @Joachim After some thinking and reading @Chris's answer i've realised (at least i think so) that using `< >` style includes will have the same effect on `.` as using `" "` and `-I-`, removing it from the search path for that inclusion. Removing the `.` is not in my interest i only want to search it AFTER `Common` has been searched.

Comment: Actually, after an additional search, it looks like `-iquote` may be what you are looking for. Take a look [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html)

Comment: @JamesH No not really. Even though you can't see it when using `-verbose` the "current directory" is unfortunately searched before directories added using either `-iquote<dir>` or `-I<dir>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are having is with `#include "`...`"` as opposed to `#include <`...`>`

With a normal C compiler, using the `"` form always searches in the same directory as the current file, and *then* looks in the include path set by `-I`.  If you want to search somewhere else before looking in the current file's directory, there's no easy way to do it.

You can use gcc's `-I-` to *inhibit* searching in the current file's directory, and add other directories to use only for `"` include files (not for `<>`), but if you use that, there's no way to get back the behavior of searching in the current file's directory.

You can try something like:

```
-ICommon -I. -I- -Iwhatever
```

This will search for `"` includes first in `Common`, then in the current working directory, then in `whatever` (and the rest of the normal path), while `<>` will start in `whatever`.  Unfortunately, it will never search in the current file's directory, if that is different from the current working directory.

`-I-` is also deprecated, so may go away soon.

Comment: It would seem the soultion using GCC's inlude options is a dead end for me then since the "current file's directory" is quite important if source in directory A is including headers in directory B who in turn also is including headers in directory B. This if `-IB `is not added to the option list but that would leave an unmaintainable, long list of options in the Makefile. It's a great answer but i won't mark it as the accepted one yet if someone comes up with a work around! Thanks!

Comment: The solution i choose for my problem was to clone all the Halcogen headers containing hardware references using a Python script. That same Pyhton script also replaces all hardware addresses with actual observable an mutable varaibles. This solution is only working since the Halcogen layer is only subjected to change if the usage of processor functions and peripherals change, wich is rare in most mature embedded projects. Answer marked as accepted.